# JMeter: How to access a remote Cloud directory in JMeter?

Tags: jmeter, cloud, jmeter-plugins

I need to access a ***remote cloud directory ( microsoft azure)*** to list the files in the folder. I also need to move some of the files to another folder in the cloud directory ( cut and paste ).

I found a few answers which spoke about using a ***Beanshell Sampler*** and a ***Foreach controller*** to get the files in a directory (This was for the folder structure on my local machine). I was able to check the results using a ***Debug Sampler*** and a ***view results tree***. However, I am not sure how to use this for a Cloud directory.

I also found answers around using a ***Directory Listing Config Plugin***, this works well with the local directory as well. But I am unable to pass the path to the cloud directory.

Is there a way to access the cloud directory? I am fairly new to JMeter.
Please Help. Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're talking about [Azure Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-files-introduction) - it can be accessed either via [NFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_File_System) protocol or [SMB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Message_Block) protocol.

None of the protocols is supported by JMeter or any [plugins](https://jmeter-plugins.org/) so you will have to use [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) and write some custom Groovy code using the relevant Java library like [EMC NFS Java Client](https://github.com/EMCECS/nfs-client-java) or [JCIFS](https://www.jcifs.org/). For the latter one example code can be found in [How to Load Test SMB/CIFS with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-load-test-smb-cifs-with-jmeter), example adaptation just in case:

```
import jcifs.smb.NtlmPasswordAuthentication
import jcifs.smb.SmbFile

String url = "smb://path/to/your/cloud/directory";
NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication(null, "username", "password");
SmbFile smbFile = new SmbFile(url, auth);
SmbFile[] files = smbFile.listFiles("*");

for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    log.info("File + " + i + ": " + files[i].getName());
}
```