# JMeter: How to use the access keys to access a remote Cloud directory ( Azure Files ) in JMeter?

Tags: jmeter, cloud, azure-files

I have been trying to access the remote cloud directory ( microsoft azure) to list the files in the folder and to perform a few file/folder operations in the cloud directory.
I had previously asked a similar question:
[JMeter: How to access a remote Cloud directory in JMeter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71266646/jmeter-how-to-access-a-remote-cloud-directory-in-jmeter)

However, I am looking to use the Access keys ( Connection string and Key) to access these files from JMeter. Is there a way to do so?
Thank you in advance.

[Azure Access Keys](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wOnfM.png)

Answer (score 0):

As per [View account access keys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-account-keys-manage?tabs=azure-powershell#view-account-access-keys) documentation entry you could use [Get-AzStorageAccountKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.Storage/Get-azStorageAccountKey?view=azps-7.3.0) cmdlet in [Powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/) to read your access keys.

In JMeter you can invoke Powershell commands using [OS Process Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-external-commands-and-programs-locally-and-remotely-jmeter)